# CONCAT function to append the column values to export data to CSV file

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

CONCAT function will set '' for NULL values but when append the column values with comma (,) separated then it not giving the expected result.
Below is the sample query

```sql
    CREATE TABLE DEST_TABLE (ExportData VARCHAR(MAX))
    
    CREATE TABLE SOURCE_TABLE (COLUMN_1 VARCHAR(10), COLUMN_2 VARCHAR(10), COLUMN_3 VARCHAR(10), COLUMN_4 VARCHAR(10))
    
    INSERT INTO SOURCE_TABLE (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3, COLUMN_4)
    VALUES ('COLUMN1', 'COLUMN2', 'COLUMN3', 'COLUMN4'), 
    (NULL, 'COLUMN2', 'COLUMN3', 'COLUMN4'), ('COLUMN1', NULL, 'COLUMN3', 'COLUMN4'), 
    ('COLUMN1', 'COLUMN2', NULL, 'COLUMN4'), ('COLUMN1', 'COLUMN2', 'COLUMN3', NULL )
    
    INSERT INTO DEST_TABLE (ExportData)
    SELECT CONCAT (COLUMN_1, + ',' + COLUMN_2, + ',' + COLUMN_3, + ',' + COLUMN_4) FROM SOURCE_TABLE
    
    SELECT ExportData FROM DEST_TABLE
```

The output is
COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4 -- It is correct
,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4        -- It is correct
COLUMN1,COLUMN3,COLUMN4         -- **It is NOT correct**
COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN4         -- **It is NOT correct**
COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3         -- It is correct

The Expected Output should be
COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4
,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4
COLUMN1,,COLUMN3,COLUMN4  -- Extra comma added b/w Column1 and Column3
COLUMN1,COLUMN2,,COLUMN4  -- Extra comma added b/w Column2 and Column4
COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3

Please help me to add extra comma when the column holding NULL value.

Comment: The problem is that `'Literal String' + NULL = NULL`, that's why you are losing the commas.

Answer (score 1):

Small changes in the `SELECT` statement resolves the issue. Remove plus(+) and add comma(,) in required places.

```
SELECT CONCAT (COLUMN_1,',',COLUMN_2,',',COLUMN_3,',',COLUMN_4)
```